# Storing System Settings in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, switch-statement, datastore

I was wondering what the best way to store a singular systems settings, as a traditional table is considered to have more than 1 row in that table, but in this case, I will only ever need 1 row, therefore I'd need to have an initial insert statement to create, I'd much rather that there was just a set table that I could alter or something similar, it might be a silly thought, but I just wanted to check up on it?

Comment: This is fine. What's your concern? Some use the [Attribute Value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-value_system) for this.

Comment: It's not a concern, I'd just rather not have to execute an insert every time I recreate the tables, I'm more concerned about re-usability.

Comment: Wait, why are you recreating the tables? Altering the table to say add a column, you keep the current values, unless any new constraints invalidate them.

Comment: It's a system, systems should be designed to be portable and robust.

Comment: Consider adding more details so that we understand the issue.